# How to use nemo actions to mount an iso file?

Tags: files, arch-linux, mount, iso, nemo

I read these articles:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nemo
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mounting_images_as_user

and try use `Nemo Actions` to mount `iso` files but nothing happened while I clicked the context menu option.

My steps:

1. `sudo pacman -S fuseiso`
2. create `nemo-actions-iso-mount.sh` in `/usr/bin/`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash    
   FILE=$(basename "$1")    
   MOUNTPOINT="$HOME/Desktop/$FILE"  
   fuseiso -p "$1" "$MOUNTPOINT"
   ```
3. `sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/nemo-actions-iso-mount.sh`
4. create the script `mountiso.nemo_action` in `$HOME/.local/share/nemo/actions/`

   ```
   [Nemo Action]   
   Name=Mount Image File: %N   
   Comment=Create an folder in ~/Desktop with the name of the image file   
   Exec=/usr/bin/nemo-actions-iso-mount.sh %N    
   Selection=S   
   Extensions=iso;nrg;bin;img;mdf;    
   Mimetypes=*/*
   ```

Comment: Does nemo maybe need to be restarted for it to reload the actions?

Comment: I did it,otherwise it would not show the new context menu option

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the reason:the field `Exec` isn't support the parameter `%N`, should use `%F` instead.